# how to fix a template using jinja2?

Tags: python, jinja2

I'm trying to filter the output of data from the database using jinja2 in the template, but it gives an error below, I don't understand what this might be related to

```
 File "templates/admin.html", line 187, in template
    {% endfor %}
jinja2.exceptions.TemplateSyntaxError:Encountered unknown tag 'endfor'. You probably made a nesting mistake.
Jinja is expecting this tag, but currently looking for 'elif' or 'else' or
'endif'. The innermost block that needs to be closed is 'if'.
```

**my template:**

```
{% for fd in foods %}
<div class="list__item">
    <span>{{ fd.food_name }}</span>
    <div class="switch-btn"></div>
</div>
{% endfor %}
</div>
<div class="order__container">
    {% for order in orders %}
            {% if order.ready_status|string() == new_order|string() %}
                <div class="order__item orange">
                    <span class="order__num">Заказ № {{ order.id }}</span>
                    <span class="order__elem">{{ order.food.food_name }}-{{ order.food_counter }}</span>
                    <span class="order__sum">Итог {{ order.total_price }}</span>
                </div>
            {% if order.ready_status|string() == adopted|string() %}
                <div class="order__item green">
                    <span class="order__num">Заказ № {{ order.id }}</span>
                    <span class="order__elem">{{ order.food.food_name }}-{{ order.food_counter }}</span>
                    <span class="order__sum">Итог {{ order.total_price }}</span>
                </div>
            {% else %}
                <div class="order__item blue">
                    <span class="order__num">Заказ № {{ order.id }}</span>
                    <span class="order__elem">{{ order.food.food_name }}-{{ order.food_counter }}</span>
                    <span class="order__sum">Итог {{ order.total_price }}</span>
                </div>
            {% endif %}
    {% endfor %}
</div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Guess the second `if` should be a `elif`. Thus:

````
template = """{% for fd in foods %}
<div class="list__item">
    <span>{{ fd.food_name }}</span>
    <div class="switch-btn"></div>
</div>
{% endfor %}
</div>
<div class="order__container">
    {% for order in orders %}
            {% if order.ready_status|string() == new_order|string() %}
                <div class="order__item orange">
                    <span class="order__num">Заказ № {{ order.id }}</span>
                    <span class="order__elem">{{ order.food.food_name }}-{{ order.food_counter }}</span>
                    <span class="order__sum">Итог {{ order.total_price }}</span>
                </div>
            {% elif order.ready_status|string() == adopted|string() %}
                <div class="order__item green">
                    <span class="order__num">Заказ № {{ order.id }}</span>
                    <span class="order__elem">{{ order.food.food_name }}-{{ order.food_counter }}</span>
                    <span class="order__sum">Итог {{ order.total_price }}</span>
                </div>
            {% else %}
                <div class="order__item blue">
                    <span class="order__num">Заказ № {{ order.id }}</span>
                    <span class="order__elem">{{ order.food.food_name }}-{{ order.food_counter }}</span>
                    <span class="order__sum">Итог {{ order.total_price }}</span>
                </div>
            {% endif %}
    {% endfor %}
</div>
    </div>```
````